# making a simple guestbook

Tags: php, html, forms

If you have an html and you sumbit it to a basic PHP file receiver, I wonder how you make them add up. how do you make the submitted forms stack instead of each submission replacing the other? I have no clue where to even start looking for an answer.

wrap print statements and make wrap element an array?
do i need file I/O for this so the messages get stored somewhere?

PHP is a very confusing jungle for me at the moment. Note that I haven't gotten to the database part of php in my course yet.

many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried google? I'm sure there are thousands of guestbook tutorials for PHP on the web.

Comment: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/15.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you will need file I/O to store messages.
Otherwise how they are supposed to be saved? 
So, you have to save your messages in a file.

To add new data at the bottom of the file you have to append it instead of rewriting.

if you're using `file_put_contents` function, use it with FILE_APPEND flag:

```
file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

if you're using `fopen()`, use `'a'` mode instead of `'w'`

Answer (score 2):

You could store data in files like @Col. Shrapnel has answered.

However, if you are going to create a guestbook that also will be used online, I would recommend learning to work with databases. It would be good practice.

A database helps you to organize your data in a logical manner.

Comment: I understand that databases are normally the way to go. But I'm pretty sure that the challenge here is to be able to do it without a database and then after that with the database.

Comment: @Jack_Anyway: Why would you avoid using databases? Would you like to store the messages in files or sessions? I think it will only make it harder. If you are storing the data in files, there is a chance you overwrite the whole data if for example two users submit the data at the same time.

Comment: @Michiel one who do not understand filesystem I/O basics will get no good from databases. You can see consequences here on SO

Comment: Databases store it's info in the same files, dude.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to store data between submissions, you can store in is the `_SESSION` variable, just call `session_start` at the beginning of your program. Messages can be stored in a file, for example. You can use sqlite as a database if you wish.

What do you mean by wrapping?

Comment: same thing with sessionvariables. they are for a later chapter in my course but thanks for your answer. 
wrapping I meant wrapping print statements with overarching HTML element but scratch that I was only brainstorming