# make an array out of guestbookmessages?

Tags: php, html, stack

Got the [guestbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402772/making-a-simple-guestbook/5402850#5402850) working alright. New messages are building up nicely.
Now, only the 10 most recent messages need to show using LIFO structure.

My course still requires I don't use database or session variables, so I'm still using  I/O exclusively here.

```
<?php
  $message = "<p><b>naam: </b>$_POST[naam] <br>
                <b>email: </b>$_POST[email] <br>
                <b>onderwerp: </b>$_POST[subj]<br><br>
                <b>bericht: </b>$_POST[bericht]<br>
                <b>verzonden op: </b> $datum
                </p>
                <hr/>";
            if (is_writable ($file)){
                $fp= fopen($file, "a")
                        or die ("can't open file");
                    fwrite ($fp, $message);
                    fclose($fp);

                }//end if writable
            else {
                print ("can't write to file");
                }   
            if (is_readable($file)){
                $fp = fopen($file, "r");
                $message = fread ($fp, filesize($file));
                fclose ($fp);
                print ($message);
                }
            else {
                print("can't read file");}
    }//end else (variables not empty)
?>
```

so I guess the idea here is to have $message be an array and then sort of having it count to ten and then keep popping off the end each time a new message comes along. Then I figured just declaring `$message []` doesn't work and now I'm pretty much clueless.ak

Comment: Don't know what structure of file is other than that it's a plain text and writing to and reading from works. Messages do show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, **extremely lame** solution would be to read whole file into memory, and *explode* it's contents into separate array elements.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$messages = explode("<hr/>",$contents);
```

However, to make your guestbook reliable one you have to change format of your datafile.

In the past years, when most guestbooks were such flat file-based, most common format were like this:

name|email|title|date|message

where only data were saved with no formatting, each message on a separate line and fields separated by some special character or group of characters.
Such text-file based solution isn't too reliable too, but at least it can be handled without risk of overloading available memory.

Comment: yes something like that works, looks like that is also what the exercise intended. Thanks, Col. Shrapnel!

Comment: Even though I find it hard to refuse code as an answer to my question basically what i'm always trying to  ask is if my thinking is on the right track or not; but thanks for your feedback Sharpnel. It means my questions don't come across that way so I look out for that in the future.